# How can you find an eigenpair given an approximate eigenvector

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Generally speaking, given the eigenvalue problem $\mathbf{A} v = \lambda v$ with a given complex non-Hermetian matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and an approximate eigenvector $u$, what ways exist to numerically determine the most similar eigenvector and its corresponding eigenvalue?

To give more detail, I am dealing with a problem where I have a large complex non-Hermetian matrix ($n=1000$ at its most manageable), but I am only interested in one eigenvector and eigenvalue. I can approximate this eigenvector and (and the complex part of its eigenvalue) to good accuracy by eigendecomposing a much smaller matrix, as I know that the first few elements of the eigenvector will be very similar to the eigenvector of the smaller matrix and all other elements will be very small. Does there exist a computationally efficient way to numerically refine the eigenvector and eigenvalue of this larger matrix?

Comment: Is your matrix dense or sparse?

Comment: Your matrix must be very special for you to do the initial approximation. You should add these special details to increase the chance of getting a useful answer.

Comment: The matrix is dense for the $n=1000$ case but becomes sparse as I add more elements so that $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I don't actually know why (from a mathematical perspective) I am able to do the initial approximation. I know that the physical interpretation of the matrix is that the smaller elements governs the oscillation of the physical problem that I am attempting to simulate, and the additional elements govern the relaxation of that problem. So from a physical perspective, the initial approximation must work, but I don't understand why it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You might have a chance using [inverse iteration](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node96.html).

Computing all eigenvalues and eigenvalues of an $n$ by $n$ dense matrix $A$ matrix requires $O(n^3)$ arithmetic operations. The modern approach involves three phases. First $A$ is reduced to upper Hessenberg form $$H = Q_1^* A Q_1$$ using unitary similarity transformations. Here $H$ is upper Hessenberg and $Q_1$ is unitary. In LAPACK the relevant subroutine is [ZGEHRD](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d01/group__complex16_g_ecomputational_ga4de4b424a4c7b0a78f7138a94ec54671.html). Second, $H$ is reduced to complex Schur form $$S = Q_2^* H Q_2$$ using unitary similarity transformations. Here $S$ is upper triangular and $Q_2$ is unitary. This is the celebrated QR algorithm. In LAPACK the relevant subroutine is [ZHSEQR](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d0/da6/group__complex16_o_t_h_e_rcomputational_ga72a026b11daa19641a162d05b8b1e0c9.html). Finally, the user's selection of eigenvectors of $S$ are computed using a variant of backsubstitution with dynamical scaling of the eigenvectors to prevent overflow. In LAPACK the relevant subroutine is [ZTREVC](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d0/da6/group__complex16_o_t_h_e_rcomputational_ga7ba72e3f9dc4b97e17f7888df9cbc005.html). 
The routine call also back-transform the eigenvectors to the original basis for $A$.

The cost of each stage is $O(n^3)$ arithmetic operations, but these asymptotic estimates are very deceptive. The reduction to Hessenberg form contains a memory bound component which is very time consuming. The eigenvector computation in LAPACK is a sequential scalar code that computes the eigenvectors one by one. This is inefficient on modern computers.

In contrast, the inverse iteration requires a single $LU$ factorization and the solution of a single linear system per iteration. The cost of the factorization is $O(n^3)$ aritmetic operations, but the $LU$ factorization routine in LAPACK is compute bound. The subroutine is called [ZGETRF](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/da/d30/a18643_ga5b625680e6251feb29e386193914981c.html). The linear solves cost $O(n^2)$ arithemtic operations each because you can reuse the factorization. The relevant subroutines are [ZGETRS](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d01/group__complex16_g_ecomputational_ga3a5b88a7e8bf70591e521e86464e109d.html) if you do not worry about floating-point overflow and [ZLATRS](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/de/d99/a18656_gab1dbea06bfa3c8dc0f7042a76dadd749.html) if you do. Granted, the linear solves are memory bound, but you do not need that many of them if you initial guess is good enough.

Inverse iteration becomes even more attractive when your matrix is large and sparse. You may have to use inverse subspace iteration to overcome clustering of your eigenvalues, but that is a topic for a separate question.