# Estimate overlap of trial state $x$ with the (unknown) eigenvector $x_0$ of a real symmetric, sparse matrix H

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose we have a very large, sparse, real symmetric matrix $H$ of dimension $n$ ($n > 10^7$). Being diagonalizable, it has a spectrum of eigenpairs $(\mathbf{x}_i, \lambda_i)$. The problem is the following: given a trial vector-value pair $(\mathbf{x}, \lambda)$, what are some known ways to lower bound (and upper, if possible) the dot product $\mathbf{x}_0 \cdot \mathbf{x}$ -- "the overlap", or "ground state support" -- without computing the spectrum of $H$ directly?

Because the matrix is so large, assume that it is impractical to compute the spectrum directly, even with the best available methods (QR algorithm, etc.). However, since $H$ is sparse, assume that certain matrix operations involving $H$ are allowed (e.g. acting with $H$ on the trial vector, taking powers of $H$ up to some reasonable number).

What I tried:

I wondered if perhaps this could use the fact that eigenpairs of $H$ must obey certain properties? Some of the relevant properties I identified include

- The variance of an eigenvector, $\mathbf{x}^t \cdot H^2 \cdot \mathbf{x} - (\mathbf{x}^t \cdot H \cdot \mathbf{x} )^2$, vanishes (the Weisenstein eigenvalue bound could be re-stated in a form related to the overlap). In practice this looks like a very loose bound.
- Eigenvectors of $H$ are fixed points of the map $F: x \rightarrow Hx$,
- The Krylov subspace-generating sequence $\mathbf{x}, H\mathbf{x}, H^2\mathbf{x},...$ becomes trivial for an eigenvector -- could "how much it does not terminate" be a metric?
- For a high enough power $k$ of $H$, the difference $||H^k\cdot\mathbf{x} - ( (H^k \cdot \mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{x} ) \mathbf{x}||$ preferentially measures the distance of the trial vector to the eigenvector of $H$ with the largest eigenvalue (a-la power method).

The most relevant literature I found refers to this problem as "eigenvector verification" or "eigenvector error bounds": Krawczyk's method, Moore's ansatz using Brouwer's fixeed point theorem, and others are well-described in the introduction of this [SIAM publication](https://doi.org/10.1137/21M1451440) (paywall). However, the literature reviewed there is sparse, a bit dated, and a lot of it has not been translated to English (unfortunately the only language accessible to me).

Moreover, the algorithms described in [some of this literature](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01396059) (paywalled, see an [earlier similar paper](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article-abstract/4/3/230/380568) that is open-access)  require inversion of a matrix that includes $H$ as a submatrix, which does not seem any less complex than diagonalizing $H$ directly. And the only examples given are for matrices of size 3 by 3, which raises doubts about whether this would work for a very large matrix.

Note: I checked out the seemingly related question posed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607146/how-can-you-find-an-eigenpair-given-an-approximate-eigenvector), however I hope that because I am not actually interested in knowing the eigenpair, just knowing how bad my guess is, that there is a different approach that scales better than the inverse iteration method mentioned in that link above.

Comment: It is hard to know exactly what you are asking. Your title question is distinctly different from the questions in the beginning of your main text. Your title question can be solved immediately by computing the backward error associated with the pair $(\lambda,x)$. With the restrictions that you have imposed on $H$ it is not impossible to apply the either the inverse subspace iteration or the Tracemin algorithm and compute the eigenvectors corresponding to, say, the 5 smallest eigenvalues. When this information is available, then all your questions can be answered.

Comment: In your case, are there additional restrictions on the matrix or the machinery so that is impractical to solve linear systems of the form $(H-\alpha I)x=f$? This would preclude applying either of the two algorithms that I mentioned.

Comment: You are right, my apologies for the confusion between the title and the body (it is mostly because I view these as related questions). I will fix this now. By backward error, do you mean the difference $Hx - \lambda x$? I think this measures "how far is $x$ from the entire spectrum of $H$" and not so much how far it is from any particular eigenvector (say $x_0$).

Comment: Solving linear systems of the form you specify should be possible for my case. What are the largest matrices that inverse subspace iteration and/or Tracemin can be reliably applied to? I think scale is the biggest concern.

Comment: The backward error $\eta$ measures the size of the perturbation $\Delta H$ such that $(\lambda,x)$ is an eigenpair for $H + \Delta H$. Specifically, $\eta = \min \{ \epsilon > 0 \: : \: (H + \Delta H)x = \lambda x \wedge \|\Delta H\| \leq \epsilon \|H\|\}$. A theorem by Rigal and Gache ensures that $\eta = \|Hx-\lambda x\|/(\|H\|\|x\|)$. The size of a sparse linear system is our primary concern. We can either reorder the matrix and factor it directly or we cannot. We can either find a good preconditioner or we cannot.

Comment: To answer these questions it is necessary to study your matrices directly.